# How to read multiple data types from file in c

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I have to read a file that contains a list of groceries, each line has 3 parts: category, name, price

So this is what the file looks like:

```
Fruit,Apple,15.6
Vegetable,Potato,20.0
Fruit,Banana,17.0
Vegetable,Lettuce,13.5
```

I'm having trouble with reading those values and putting them into a linked list.

I believe that the only problem I have is with reading them correctly and loading them into a linked list. I've tried many different combinations with *fscanf*, but none seem to work.

```
        typedef struct Grocery Grocery;

        struct Grocery
        {
            char category[100];
            char name[100];
            float price;
            Grocery *next;
        };

        Grocery *addNew(char *category, char *name, float price)
        {
            Grocery *newN = (Grocery*)malloc(sizeof(Grocery));

            strcpy(newN->category, category);
            strcpy(newN->name, name);
            newN->price = price;
            newN->next = NULL;

            return newN;
        }

        Grocery *add_on_beginning(Grocery *head, Grocery *newN)
        {
            newN->next = head;

            return newN;
        }

        Grocery *load_file(Grocery *head)
        {
            char filename[100];

            scanf("%s", filename);

            FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

            char *category;
            char *name;
            float price;

            if(fp == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error in loading file.\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                while(!feof(fp))
                {
                    fscanf(fp, "%s,%s,%lf\n", category, name, &price);

                    Grocery *newN = addNew(category, name, price);

                    head = add_on_beginning(head, newN);
                }
            }

            fclose(fp);

            printf("File loaded successfully.\n");

            return head;
        }
```

Whenever I debug the code, I get random numbers and letters after every element is printed, I get this:

> ï&╪5Ç@ 0.000000

[image]

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all the help, I've made it work with this `while(fscanf(fp, "%[^,],%[^,],%f\n", category, name, &price) == 3)`, can someone explain what it does?

Comment: `error in loading file` is *not* a useful error message. Use `perror(filename)`

Comment: Variables `char *category; char *name;` do not have any memory allocated to them. Also please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) You should drive the loop with the result of `fscanf` such as `while(fscanf(...) == 3) { ... }`. Also`%lf` is the wrong format specifier in `fscanf` for a `float`, it should be `%f`.

Comment: I've changed the code, for while condition, I put this while(fscanf(fp, "%s,%s,%f\n", category, name, &price) == 3), I also changed char *category to char category[100], same with name, now when I debug the program, the list won't even print.

Comment: You're not checking the return value of `fscanf` or `scanf`. That would be a start.

Comment: ...and so the program cannot produce the result you show for the input you give, because it has no whitespace within each line.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
    typedef struct Grocery Grocery;

    struct Grocery
    {
        char category[100];
        char name[100];
        float price;
        Grocery *next;
    };

    Grocery *addNew(char *category, char *name, float price)
    {
        Grocery *newN = (Grocery*)malloc(sizeof(Grocery));

        strcpy(newN->category, category);
        strcpy(newN->name, name);
        newN->price = price;
        newN->next = NULL;

        return newN;
    }

    Grocery *add_on_beginning(Grocery *head, Grocery *newN)
    {
        newN->next = head;

        return newN;
    }

    Grocery *load_file(Grocery *head)
    {
        char filename[100];

        scanf("%s", filename);

        FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

        char category[100];
        char name[100];
        float price;

        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error in loading file.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            while(fscanf(fp, "%[^,],%[^,],%f\n", category, name, &price) == 3))
            {
                Grocery *newN = addNew(category, name, price);

                head = add_on_beginning(head, newN);
            }
        }

        fclose(fp);

        printf("File loaded successfully.\n");

        return head;
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend you change `"%[^,],%[^,],%f\n"` to `" %[^,],%[^,],%f"`. The leading space tells `fscanf` to filter out leading whitespace from the input, and it is generally recommended not to try to match any trailing newline, which may or may not be present (such as the last line in a file).